# Custom clientside regex validation in an html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to validate a form input type text. The value should be ending in ".tar.gz" and should have some keywords. Anyways I have the regex ready, but I am stuck on how to validate this without pressing submit. Kind of like how "pattern" attribute works. Any suggestions?
this is the row which needs to be validated and the submit button already has a function to disable the button after 1st click. as shown below.

```
<tr> <td>Suite Name</td> <td><input type='text' name='same' id='sname' title='Default suite name format: autosuite_<signum>_timestamp'/></td> </tr> 

<input type='submit' name='launch' id='launch' onclick='setTimeout(disableFunction, 1)' value='Launch'/><br>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? May we see your code?

Comment: I was trying to use the same regex in pattern attribute but, the $ and ^ does not work in HTML.
<tr>
<td>Suite Name</td>
<td><input type='text' name='same' id='sname' title='Default suite name format: autosuite_<signum>_timestamp'/></td>
</tr>

this is the row which needs to be validated and the submit button already has a function to disable the button after 1st click. as shown below.

<input type='submit' name='launch' id='launch' onclick='setTimeout(disableFunction, 1)' value='Launch'/><br>

Comment: What I mean is, that's not how you ask a question on SO. You need to try something and show your code. You can't just ask "Hey guys, I've got some random problem, do you have a miracle solution? - Yeah sure, let me guess".

Comment: (Show your code in the original question, not in comments. Properly formatted and all :)

Comment: I asked "any suggestions?" I was not asking for a clear cut solution right away. I tried a lot of things, they didnt work out, removed them from the code. You want me to copy paste all those wrong functions I wrote?

Comment: Well, I think the answer below worked, testing inputs now, will update.

Comment: Well, on SO, we're not supposed to develop stuff for you. You come with a broad problem and ask, "suggest me how to do". It's not how it works here. Here is a place where wou come with your code, which should work, but doesn't. Then, people help you finding why. That's why you have been downvoted (not by me). Why am I so nice today? We usually like kicking newbies' butts :)

Comment: Well I admit I am a beginner right now, but will take care of these things in future. Thanks for the headsup though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the String.search() method like:

```
var str = document.getElementById("yourinputelementid").value;
var n = str.search("regexpression");
```

Will return -1 if it doesn't exist or the index of the match if it does exist.  If you want to do validation without pressing submit call a method to test string onkeyup event of your input.

Comment: It worked, rather than using str.search I used .test which I was using before.
    var n = /\/[a-z0-9_\.-]*(SDK)[a-z0-9_\.-]*\.tar\.gz$/i.test(string);
this is the regular exp I am using.
Thanks.